# give information on vs show

Tags: word-choice, difference

I think that the first sentence is about the general information of the table and pie charts whereas the second sentence provides more detailed information. Is this the reason why "give information on" is used in the first sentence while "show" is used in the second? I mean if "give information" is used to introduce general information whilst "show" is used to introduce more specific information. Or am I thinking too much and they can be switched?

> The table and charts below **give information on** the police budget for 2017 and
> 2018 in one area of Britain. The table **shows** where the money came from and
> the charts **show** how it was distributed.

([prompt image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud2Gq.jpg))

Comment: to give information on something and to show something are not the same expression.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are my reasons why the first sentence uses "give information on" while the second sentence uses "show" correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The expressions could be reversed* **but** in writing authors often start with a general idea and then move to the specific idea.

So, together, those things give information on A for some years.

And they also show A and B.

*give information on* is a pretty general idea.

*show* is often used to refer to numbers in charts/tables.